# Why aren't some fontAwesome icons missing?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome

I want to connect fa in vue Doing

```
*************
import { library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome'
import { faVuejs } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'
******************
library.add(faVuejs);
Vue.component('font-awesome-icon', FontAwesomeIcon)
************
```

In component:

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="[ 'fab', 'twitter' ]" />
```

Console error:

```
Could not find one or more icon(s) {prefix: "fab", iconName: "twitter"}
```

But, if im use:

```
<font-awesome-icon :icon="[ 'fab', 'vuejs' ]" />
```

Working fine ... What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import the `faTwitter` icon, and add it to the library like you're doing with the Vue icon:

```js
import { faTwitter } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons'

library.add(faTwitter)
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/using-twitter-icon-with-vue-fontawesome-sukb5?file=/src/main.js:177-296)